# How to allow just round hour in Django models.TimeField?

Tags: django, database, django-models

I want to add a `models.TimeField` field to my **Django** table.

And restrict the user so that he can only add a round hour (e.g. 13:00 but not 13:30).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Add extra validation for that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an extra [*validator* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_round_hour(value):
    if not value.minute == value.second == value.microsecond == 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            'This should be a round hour.',
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

then you can add the validiator to your model field:

```
class SomeField(models.Model):
    some_time = models.TimeField(validators=[validate_round_hour])
```

Note that this will *not* be enforced at the database level. But a form will run the validators, and thus can prevent a user entering invalid data.